# What if "echo $?" command returns 2?

Tags: linux, shell, echo

I know that, to see our last executed command is correct is shell, we use "`echo $?`" command.
And why it is returning 2 as output and what does it means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should focus last command before echo $?.open that command man page. you could find the meaning of exit code.

For example;

```
man grep;
...
EXIT STATUS
The exit status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if not found.  
If an error occurred the exit status is 2.  
(Note: POSIX error handling code should check for '2' or greater.)
....
```

or

```
man ls;

   Exit status:
       0      if OK,

       1      if minor problems (e.g., cannot access subdirectory),

       2      if serious trouble (e.g., cannot access command-line argument).
```

or

```
man diff

 Exit status is 0 if inputs are
       the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble.
```

Answer (score 2):

It simply displays the error code of the last command. Check this link: [Linux System Errors](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html)

```
#define ENOENT           2      /* No such file or directory */
```

Comment: Or on debian type `$ cat usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h`